# More efficient way to search through Pandas groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to get the list of values from `col2` that belong to the same `groupId`, given corresponding value in `col1`. `Col1` values can belong to multiple groups and in that case only top-most group should be considered (group 2 but not group 3 in my example). `Col1` values are always identical within the same `groupId`.

| groupId | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | a | 10 |
| 1 | b | 20 |
| 2 | a | 30 |
| 1 | b | 40 |
| 3 | a | 50 |
| 3 | a | 60 |
| 1 | b | 70 |

My current solution takes over 30s for a `df` with 2000 rows and 32 values to search for in `col1` ('a' in this case):

```
group_id_groups = df.groupby('groupId') 

for group_id, group in group_id_groups:
    col2_values = list(group[group['col1'] == 'a']['col2'])
    if col2_values:
        print(col2_values)
        break


result: [10, 30]
```

Comment: Please don't only explain but show us your expected output. This make it easier to understand your needs. Have a look at `pandas.DataFrame.groupby()`.

Comment: If I search for 'a' in col1, [10, 30] is the expected output.

Comment: Does something like `df[df["col1"].eq("a")].groupby("groupId")["col2"].unique()` provide your expected result?

Comment: @sierra_papa but what is the logic to pick groupId ==2 only. Just cos it's the first to appear?

Comment: So if you picked 'b' what would the expected results be?

Comment: @rpanai Correct, the first one to appear.

Comment: @ ArchAngelPwn [20,40,70]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sort` parameter of groupby defaults to true, which means the first group will be the topmost by default.  You can change the `col_to_search` to `b` and get the other answer.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'groupId': [2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1],
 'col1': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'],
 'col2': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]})

col_to_search = 'a'
(
    df.loc[df['col1'].eq(col_to_search)]
    .groupby('groupId')['col2']
    .apply(list)
    .iloc[0]
)
```

Output

```
[10, 30]
```

Comment: As groupby order the column if you use 'groupId': [3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1] this doesn't return the first group in `df`.

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure what you want. Does this help you? I am sure that `pandas.DataFrame.groupby()` is your friend here.

#### Full code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

# initial data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'groupId': [2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1],
    'col1': list('ababaab'),
    'col2': range(10, 80, 10)
})
print(df)

g = df.groupby(['groupId', 'col1']).agg(list)
print(g)

result = g.loc[(2, 'a')]
print(result)
```

#### Step by step

Your initial data in `df` looks like this

```
    groupId col1  col2
 0        2    a    10
 1        1    b    20
 2        2    a    30
 3        1    b    40
 4        3    a    50
 5        3    a    60
 6        1    b    70
```

Then you simply group your data by your two "search columns". The result per group is stored as a `list`.

```
g = df.groupby(['groupId', 'col1']).agg(list)
```

The result:

```
                      col2
groupId col1              
1       b     [20, 40, 70]
2       a         [10, 30]
3       a         [50, 60]
```

No you can do your search:

```
result = g.loc[(2, 'a')]
```

That gives you

```
col2    [10, 30]
Name: (2, a), dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`agg(list)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) then search what you want with [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and return the first find.

```
>>> grp = df.groupby(['groupId', 'col1']).agg(list).reset_index()

>>> grp.loc[grp['col1'].eq('a'), 'col2'].to_list()[0]
[10, 30]

>>> grp.loc[grp['col1'].eq('a'), 'col2']
1    [10, 30]
2    [50, 60]
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you mostly need to create a mask without using a groupby.

```py
import pandas as pd

# data
data = {'groupId': {0: '2', 1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '1', 4: '3', 5: '3', 6: '1'},
 'col1': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'a', 3: 'b', 4: 'a', 5: 'a', 6: 'b'},
 'col2': {0: 10, 1: 20, 2: 30, 3: 40, 4: 50, 5: 60, 6: 70}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# First group where condition is satisfied
first_group = df[df["col1"].eq("a")].iloc[0]["groupId"]

# Output
df[df["col1"].eq("a") &
  df["groupId"].eq(first_group)]["col2"].to_list()
```

And the output is `[10, 30]` as expected.